# why aren't my npx and npm commands working?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, npm, npx

both of my node and npm are up to date but when i try to create a vite project :
I type `npm create vite@latest`
it creates as it should then i type `npm install` 
and that goes as planned too but when i type `npm run dev` i get this error:

```
(node:18812) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??='
    at Loader.moduleStrategy (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:145:18)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:18812) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:18812) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

and i created my project with yarn and there was no problem and i installed tailwindcss too without problem but i tried using shadcn ui when i typed `npx shadcn-ui@latest init`
i got this error:

```
internal/process/esm_loader.js:74
    internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
                              ^

Error [ERR_UNKNOWN_BUILTIN_MODULE]: No such built-in module: node:timers/promises
    at new NodeError (internal/errors.js:322:7)
    at Loader.builtinStrategy (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:285:11)
    at new ModuleJob (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:63:26)
    at Loader.getModuleJob (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:258:11)
    at async ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:78:21)
    at async Promise.all (index 11)
    at async link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:83:9) {
  code: 'ERR_UNKNOWN_BUILTIN_MODULE'
}
```

and if it helps `npm install`
takes a lot of time to complete about 1 minute and everything is extremly slow
i tried installing shadcn with yarn but it wasn't initializing it(it didn't ask the question before initializing it like the way it should)

Comment: Your Node.js version is likely too old.

Comment: node version is 21.2.0

Comment: npm version is 10.2.3

Comment: Are you absolutely sure those are the versions you're actually running with? `node:timers/promises` was added in Node 15.

Comment: yes i checked npm version with npm -version and checked my node version with nvm list and it said im currently using 21.2.0

Comment: What about `node --version`? `nvm list` is not the right tool to show the current version of Node.